# Error when trying to generate random number between a range

Tags: java, random

I am trying to prompts the user for two numbers where the first number
is a min value and the second is a max value. Prompter then prompts the user for a number between the min and max numbers entered. The user should be continually prompted until a number within the range is entered. However, I get an instance error when attempting to generate a random number between the max and min range.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class MaxMin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand;

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);       

        System.out.print("Enter a min value: ");
        int max = console.nextInt();


        System.out.print("Enter a max value: ");
        int min = console.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Guess a number within the range inputted: ");
        int guess = console.nextInt();

        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min; // Error


        if (guess == randomNum) {
            System.out.print("Correct guess!");
        }

        else {
            System.out.print("Guess a number within the range inputted: ");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: When you ask for the minimum you save that value in the variable max, and when you ask for the maximum you save that value in the variable min.

Comment: Initialize your `rand` variable.

Comment: Tempted to close this as dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/3182664 - any objections?

Comment: Replace `Random rand;` with this `Random random = new Random();`